# where is a list of markdown tags supported by redcarpet gem

Tags: ruby, markdown, redcarpet

Is there is list of the markdown tags supported by the `redcarpet` gem?

For example, some markdown implementations support centering text, some don't. Rather than trial and error experimentation, it seems like such a popular gem would be documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) is responsible for the markdown - it's simply a renderer; it uses some libraries to interpret the required code

After some research, it seems all of the `markdown` interpreters are originally based on the `UpSkirt` library, which was derived from [**this Daring Fireball project**](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> Markdown is a text-to-HTML conversion tool for web writers. Markdown
>   allows you to write using an easy-to-read, easy-to-write plain text
>   format, then convert it to structurally valid XHTML (or HTML).
>
> Thus, “Markdown” is two things: (1) a plain text formatting syntax;
>   and (2) a software tool, written in Perl, that converts the plain text
>   formatting to HTML. See the Syntax page for details pertaining to
>   Markdown’s formatting syntax. You can try it out, right now, using the
>   online Dingus.

You can [find the sytnax here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)